# how can I connect a local programme to a service tunnel?

Tags: url, rabbitmq, connect, cloud-foundry, tunnel

I have tried for a week to connect a local application to a remote rabbitMQ on a CloudFoundry service but the lign:
connection = factory.newConnection();
always throws an IOException because of a java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
I have correctly followed the steps of this tutorial to create the tunnel an collect it’s informations but however it still don’t work.
Here is the lign i use for connecting my local app:

```
String rabbitMQURI = “amqp://ubSGLHE7886x6:pk6NV4xxxxxx@localhost:10100/ve296d42a44794aac92536b362681e92a”;
factory.setUri(rabbitMQURI);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to make sure that when you tried to connect your local java app to the CF rabbitmq service, you first opened a tunnel by running "vmc tunnel servicename". This will give you the connection properties: username, password, virtual_host(vhost) and port(as Dan told, it should start from 10000 if you have no other tunnels opened). You need to use the hostname "localhost". In order to use that, make sure in your hosts file 127.0.0.1 is mapped to the name "localhost".

I can connect to my own tunnel without issue with these lines of code:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setUri("amqp://usd0LnHpwPMvE:p3faI9Ug8E1au@localhost:10000/v51d86f3a7033476695655e42eaa16b1f");
    Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
```

Comment: Well, in fact even though the documentation claim not, it is possible to connect to a rabbitMQ service in POJO java !

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the port number on this is correct? If you don't have any other tunnels active, the default starting port is 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe you cannot use vmc tunnel with RabbitMQ services, only with Database services. I do not believe that the AMQP port is mapped over.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20334618-rabbitmq-service-faq and you will see that it says:

**Question:** Is the RabbitMQ service accessible to applications outside of CloudFoundry.com?

**Answer:** Not at present.